# Creating table according to selected item in DropdownList From Servlets?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have a List collection which keeps list of manager and employee names from DB. And I have another list which holds project list in a dropdownlist... When one project is selected then table must be created according to this projecet's emloyees and manager in a table... For example...

AndroidApp project selected from dropdown Then It should create a table which have names of manager and employees like this... Html table... I tried to create with jstl but i couldnt do it.

```
|manager| Employee|

 Susan   |  John

 Susan   |   Joe

 Susan   |  Megan
```

I'm developing web-app projecet with Java platform.. I have Servlets, JSP's, DB to do that. I coded Lists etc. I think my problem at this point is html coding or what else could be? My codes...

Related JSP page which is projects...

```
  <%@page import="com.eteration.leavesystem.model.Person"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ page session="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <select name="projects" multiple>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="opel">Opel</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select> <input type="submit" value="Kaydet">
    </form>
    <br>

    <script
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

    </script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#addProject").click(function(){
                $(this).next().slideToggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <button id="addProject">Proje Ekle</button>

    <div style="display:none;">
        <form action="./UserProjectServlet" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="AddedProject" /><br/>
            <button class="hidden">Ekle</button>
        </form>
    </div>
<form action="./PopulateProjectServlet" method="get">
<select name="selectedProject" id="selectedProject" onchange= "this.form.submit()" >
    <c:forEach items="${projects}" var="project">
        <option value="${project.code}">${project.desc}"</option>
    </c:forEach>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
            <caption><h2>List of users</h2></caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Manager</th>
                <th>Employees</th>         
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${projectTable}" var="projectTable">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${projectTable.pm.name}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${projectTable.e.name}" /></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I succeeded listing projects to dropdown and getting selected values id from it. Then I did onchange method to list projects informations which have names.

My result class which lists project tables info (names)

```
public class ProjectResultTableView {

    static mysqlCon con=new mysqlCon();

    public static List<ProjectTable> getProjectInfo(String projectId) throws SQLException {

        List<ProjectTable> projectTableList = new ArrayList<ProjectTable>();
        String query = "SELECT distinct e.name AS employee_name, pm.name AS manager_name FROM project_employee AS pe LEFT OUTER JOIN employee AS e ON e.employee_id = pe.employee_id LEFT OUTER JOIN project AS p ON p.project_id = pe.project_id LEFT OUTER JOIN employee AS pm ON pm.employee_id = p.manager_id WHERE pe.project_id =" +projectId+ " ;";

        Statement stmt = con.getConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        if(rs!=null){

        while (rs.next()) {

            projectTableList.add(new ProjectTable(rs.getString("pm.name"),rs.getString("e.name")));

        }

        }


        con.getConnection().close();
        return projectTableList;
    }


}
```

My SERVLET

```
@WebServlet("/ProjectResultServlet")
public class ProjectResultServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public ProjectResultServlet() {
        super();

    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



        try {
            String selectedProject = request.getParameter("selectedProject");   

            List<ProjectTable> projectTable = ProjectResultTableView.getProjectInfo(selectedProject);
            request.setAttribute("projectTable", projectTable); 
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/UserHome/Projects.jsp").forward(request, response);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        request.getRequestDispatcher("/UserHome/Projects.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

So I think its about jstl or somethhing in my html code. If there is more wrongs please help me.. My question is how can I create a table according to selected project without submitting button. I want to use onchange or something like do the same thing :) Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using Jquery, you can catch the onchange event.  Using the selectedproject do an Ajax get to the servlet and retrieve the new table.  Load the result data into a DIV.

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/